# javascript Help me with multiple timers

Tags: javascript, timer

https://jsfiddle.net/nfv02qg9/1/

I need to find a way to replace all the divs that have the word Hello! with a timer. But more divs could come in and what happens is the same variable gets rewritten. I have this on a loop to always look for Hello! with innerHTML.indexOf

summary: i need a timer to replace a word everytime it pops up. There could be 10 on the screen and more could appear later on. is there a way to make a dynamic variable that has the UTC time in it to make it unique?

```
var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("last-message fs_small");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Use a class

Comment: Do each of them have to have the same time?

Comment: Also why have the creation in an interval too?

Comment: Hello mplungjan. No they don't have to be the same time. I have an interval to keep searching for Hello! since it an appear at any time. My best summary is imagine your looking at your emails. They can appear in your inbox at anytime. I want to search for any 'emails that have the word Hello! and replace it with a timer to see how long its been there. Many emails can come in with the word hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- IDs need to be unique, use a class

```js
let clocks;
const messages = document.getElementById("messages");
const fmt = time => {
  let clock = []
  const hh = ~~(time / 3600),
    mm = ~~((time % 3600) / 60),
    ss = ~~time % 60;
  if (hh) clock.push("" + hh.toString().padStart(2, "0")); // change to != null to always get hours
  if (mm != null) clock.push(mm.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
  if (ss != null) clock.push(ss.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
  return clock.join(":")
};

const scan = setInterval(function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.message')].forEach(div => {
    if (div.textContent.includes("Hello!")) {
      div.innerHTML = `<div class="clock" data-sec="0">00:00</div>`;
    }
  });
  clocks = [...document.querySelectorAll(".message .clock")]; 
}, 2000)

const setTime = () => { 
  if (clocks && clocks.length) clocks.forEach(clock => {
    let time = +clock.dataset.sec;
    time++;
    clock.dataset.sec = time;
    clock.innerText = fmt(time); 
  });
}

setInterval(setTime, 1000);

// test: 
setInterval(function() {
  messages.innerHTML += `<div class="message">Hello!</div>`
}, 5000)
```

```html
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Comment: Hello mplungjan,

Your very close! I don't need them to be all the same. Imagine your watching your emails come in and some have the word Hello!. I want to find those emails and change Hello! to a timer that shows how long its been there. Many emails can come in with the word Hello! so I need unique timers for each to see exactly how long its been sitting in my inbox so to say!